# Cannot access ‘RoutePageModule’ before initialization

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I’m trying to use the plugin [DB-Meter](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/db-meter), however I keep getting the error Cannot access ‘RoutePageModule’ before initialization. This occurs after adding " providers:[DBMeter]" to route.module.ts.
Any tips?

```
import { DBMeter } from '@ionic-native/db-meter';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-route',
    templateUrl: './route.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./route.page.scss'],
})
export class RoutePage implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private dbMeter: DBMeter,
        public toastCtrl: ToastController,
        private platform: Platform,
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
     let subscription = this.dbMeter.start().subscribe(
               data => console.log(data));
    }
```